# WPF .png overlay using DrawingVisual

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using this example - I found around here - to overlay two .png images and then save the result as a third .png image.

The input images are:

[image: Transparent frame]

[image: Opaque background]

The output image should (in my dreams) be:

[image]

And instead I get this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        // Loads the images to tile (no need to specify PngBitmapDecoder, the correct decoder is automatically selected)
        BitmapFrame frame1 = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(@"D:\_tmp_\MaxMara\Test\Monoscope.png"), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad).Frames.First();
        BitmapFrame frame2 = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(@"D:\_tmp_\MaxMara\Test\OverlayFrame.png"), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad).Frames.First();

        // Gets the size of the images (I assume each image has the same size)
        int imageWidth = 1920;
        int imageHeight = 1080;

        // Draws the images into a DrawingVisual component
        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            drawingContext.DrawImage(frame1, new Rect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight));
            drawingContext.DrawImage(frame2, new Rect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight));
        }

        // Converts the Visual (DrawingVisual) into a BitmapSource
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, 300, 300, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(drawingVisual);

        // Creates a PngBitmapEncoder and adds the BitmapSource to the frames of the encoder
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

        // Saves the image into a file using the encoder
        using (Stream stream = File.Create(@"D:\_tmp_\MaxMara\Test\Result.png"))
            encoder.Save(stream);
    }
```

Note: if i use 100 dpi as in:

```
RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(imageWidth, imageHeight, 100, 100, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
```

I get the correct result (meaning: the result I want).

I don't understand why. All images are 300 DPI

Can anyone shed some light on the topic please?
Thank you for your time

Orf

Comment: It's not just the dpi, it's the width and height that matters. They should be equal for both. Examine at runtime and resize as needed. Probably better to go with the smaller of the two, as downsizing is more visually accurate than upsizing. *(I assume each image has the same size)* ASS U ME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` (i.e. your `imageWidth` and `imageHeight` values) of the bitmaps for drawing them into a DrawingContext.

Use their `Width` and `Height` values instead, because these give the bitmap size in [device-independent units (1/96th inch per unit)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.width(v=vs.110).aspx) as required for drawing.

```
using (var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    drawingContext.DrawImage(frame1, new Rect(0, 0, frame1.Width, frame1.Height));
    drawingContext.DrawImage(frame2, new Rect(0, 0, frame2.Width, frame2.Height));
}
```